# close cmd after running bat self-destructing bat from Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

In my Java application, I create a temporary batch file which does some work for me and the self deletes using this line `del /f /q %0`. The bat file is launched using `ProcessBuilder` and then `System.exit(0)` is called.

This workflow works perfectly, however once the batch file reaches the end I am left with a command prompt window saying "The batch file cannot be found"  and waiting for another command. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: What is the command you pass to ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @A4L The argument array looks like this `{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", tempBat.getAbsolutePath()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
del /f /q %0 &exit
```

should help

Comment: Worked an absolute treat. So simple. Thank you